# Photoshop use Preserve Details 2 in win32com

Tags: pywin32, win32com, photoshop-script

I tried to enlarge an image with win32com and i wanted to use Preserve Details 2. I figured out how to use the normal Preserve Details  (enlargement) but i dont know how to use the other one.

```
method = 9
#methods 2 = Nearest Neighbor (hard edges), 3 = Bilinear, 4 = Bicubic, 5 = Bicubic sharper, 6 = Bicubic smoother, 7 = Bicubic, 8 = auto, 9 = Preserve Details  (enlargement)
doc.ResizeImage(new_width, new_height, ppi, method, 100)
```